# Can I have two separate fakeRAID disks with two separate controllers?

Tags: raid, dmraid

I have a nv and a sil3114 SATA controllers, each has a BIOS setup Raid 5 that Needs to be shared with Windows. But I can't get either to work after trying what seems like everything.

http://samueltaylor.me.uk/2011/01/31/setting-up-nvidia-nforce-fakeraid-on-ubuntu-10-10/
libata.ignore_hpa=0

Comment: Can you add to the description of the problem? The title doesn't make much sense. FakeRAID does work with Ubuntu, having multiple controllers shouldn't matter.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You understand that *fake raid* offers no acceleration whatsoever over Linux's `mdadm` driven software RAID implementation right? The only time using *fake raid* makes sense is when you have to share that disk with Windows or another OS that doesn't understand Linux MD.